# does varnish config include statement support wildcards?

Tags: linux, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, varnish, configuration

After googling and briefly browsing varnish docs, I could not find a reference to this. Can I do for example the following in varnish vcl?

```
include sites-enabled/*.vcl
```

Answer (score 5):

No.

But as phk said, you can use the following trick :

https://www.varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-misc/2013-February/022794.html

The easy way is to:

```
cd directory
ls *.vcl | awk '{printf "include \"%s\"\n"}' > .all_includes.vcl
```

Then

```
include "directory/.all_includes.vcl"
```

Comment: The correct command is `ls *.vcl | awk '{printf "include \"%s\"\n", $1}' > .all_includes.vcl`. You have to add `, $1` to the printf.